# Connect a page to a permission group and and connect a list to a permission group

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, custom-permission-level

I have a page which i would like user that has acces on the page has READ only. I have made a group X and set to Read permissions
 On that page is a list. And I have created a new group Y with permissions Edit on that list.

- How can I set the page to the group x ?
- How can i set the list to the group y ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I set the page to the group x ?**

- Open site page, from the above ribbon, click on `page permission`

[image]

- Click on **Stop inheritance**,

[image]

- Now you can manage the permission for this page uniquely.
- Grant, the group x to access the page by click on `Grant Permission`.

[image]

---

**How can I set the list to the group y ?**

- Open list setting > Click On permission for this list
- Click on **Stop inheritance**,
- Grant, the group Y to access the page by click on `Grant Permission`.

**Also at the page level, try to do the following**

- Edit your page
- Edit the list view web part
- At `Advanced` section > at the `Target Audience` set your group Y

Comment: Waauw. You have helped me alot. Thank you. Greetings, Peter Kiers

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you! please don't forget to upvote the helpful answer :)